# Where to enable classValidatorShim and introspectComments in Nest.js

Tags: nestjs

I don't find where to enable introspectComments or classValidatorShim. It is required for some extra features of swagger plugin as it is stated in the docs:

[image]

If anybody knows it would be great

Answer (score 1):

It was further down in the documentation, in any case,i hope this post can save some time to someone.

In **nest-cli.json**

```
 "plugins": [
  {
    "name": "@nestjs/swagger",
    "options": {
      "classValidatorShim": false,
      "introspectComments": true
    }
  }
]
```

Bests